# Rails visibility function for my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add new functionality to my rails app. So I have Organization, Campaign, User and Team model.

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :members
  has_many :campains, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams
end

class Campain < ApplicationRecord    
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teamables, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :teams, through: :teamables
end

class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :organization

  has_many :teamables, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :teamables
end
```

I want to admin of campaign can choose who can view the campaign. So when he goes in admin edit campaign view he can choose one team which users can view campaign and/or choose single users who can view campaign.

I was thing of using many-to-many polymorphic association, but I do not know is that right way of doing this.

Comment: Sounds like a workable approach. Go for it!

Comment: Another alternative is to create two separate join tables for team and user privileges which would let you avoid some of the disadvantages of polymorphism such as the lack of real foreign keys.